# distinguish between "Drag" and "Touch Down then immidiately Touch Up" in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm a newbie to LibGdx,and i'm having a problem with libgdx in distinguishing between these 2 problems.
I'm making a game like canyon defense in miniclip.com.
When I touch down and then immediately touch up, a new gun will be added to a list.
But when I drag, I just want to move my camera.
My problem here is when running on Android phone HTC sensation, I couldn't detect these 2 actions, it always detects that it's a dragging action even though I just touched down and then touched up.
On PC, I've already done it, just one click or Drag, everything is done, but on Android, it's so hard, please help me :-) thank in advance :-)

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tempx = screenX;
    tempy = screenY;
    isDrag = false;
    // System.out.println(isDrag);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vector.x = screenX;
    vector.y = screenY;
    vector.z = 0;
    camera.unproject(vector);

    if ((button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) && (isDrag == false)) {
        Weapon wp = new Weapon(vector.x, vector.y);
        weapon.add(wp);
    }
    isDrag = false;
    // System.out.println(isDrag);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isDrag = true;
    if ((tempy - screenY < 0) && (isOn == true) && (num >= 0)) {
        camera.translate(new Vector3(0, 5, 0));
        num = num - 5;
    }
    if ((tempy - screenY > 0) && (isOn == true)
            && (temp.getHeight() >= num)) {
        camera.translate(new Vector3(0, -5, 0));
        num = num + 5;
    }
    tempy = screenY;
    // System.out.println(isDrag);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only set `isDrag = true;` if you are a certain distance from your `tempx` and `tempy`.

Comment: If you ever get into the scene2d api of libgdx they call it the "tap square"

Comment: thank for your idea, this's so good for me :D i'll try using it after finishing my project ^_^